# Getting the error Expected 0 arguments, but got 2 on using ternary operation

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the function where it is throwing error:

```
prepareTickerIn(value: any){
        let valueToReturn = '';

        value.map((item,i,arr) => {
            valueToReturn += (arr.length-1 == i) ? (i==0 ? item.id : 'tickerId.in='+item.id) : (i==0 ? item.id+'&' : 'tickerId.in='+item.id+'&');            
        })
        console.log(valueToReturn);
        return valueToReturn;
    }

openSearched(item: any) {
    console.log(item);
    let searchedString = this.prepareTickerIn(item);        
    this.variableRandom = searchedString;
    this.loadAll();
    return false;        
}
```

The compiler is throwing error at line 198 which is the one where I'm assigning `valueToReturn`.

Comment: There are two lines where you assign something to `valueToReturn`. Using TypeScripts Playground, I can see no error, please be more specific with your question and/or provide more code.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs when you defined the function with different argument count but while calling you're calling with a different count.

For anyone facing such problem, I was able to debug my code using the following way.
First I ran `yarn start` and there I was able to see the error and line number like it were on line number 493 which had the above-given code as in the question.

But on going through the error I found that the error was there in the build which is made by the `webpack` compiler.So I found that error was not due to the above function but some other code.

So the solution was to look there in the build and the line specified it will let you know function which causes the error then for solution.

If you are also using yarn as manager use this command for a detailed result.

`yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www`